# Besides diamonds, are there any stones without oxygen in composition?

Tags: minerals, oxides

In my inpression, the most of stones are oxides and hydroxides, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Review the guides [Asking](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to prevent misunderstanding,  need of clarification, objections, downvoting or closure.

Comment: related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75478/aside-from-carbon-what-other-substances-can-be-made-superhard

Comment: By stones you mean minerals? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_(geology)

Comment: Define «stone».  Just something «hard» like a rock? A mineral like *rock salt* (halit/NaCl)? An [iron meteorite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_meteorite)?

Comment: @Buttonwood I think, stone is something hard, brittle, non-alloy-like (insulator, no metallic luster), not volatile, crystalline (not polymeric), not molecular, not organic, non-easily solvable, not flammable, non-fibrous (non asbestos-like). Basically, a gem.

Comment: There are minerals of every kind you'd like, and you're not entitled to make some artificial definitions of words.

Comment: So biblical stoning was de facto making a heap of gems on persons being gifted.

Comment: Stone: hard solid nonmetallic mineral matter of which rock is made, especially as a building material. (Oxford dictionary)

Comment: LOL - Let's not make this complicated. For all practical purposes stones are composed of minerals. A stone may be one mineral or many. // Now the OP needs to clarify if the question is over all minerals, or the relative fraction of the minerals that compose the earth.

Comment: @Karstenyes. And rock cannot be made of volatile, easily solvable or polymeric materials.

Comment: Silicates are polymeric minerals. And rock can be soluble.

Comment: To your credit "mineral" is not an unambiguous term. However it does have a common use where it refers to compounds with a solid structure. There are other uses that might refer to liquid substances (mineral acid, or your reference to petroleum as a mineral). In that case "mineral" is an adjective that distinguishes the origin of the substance, contrasting it to an organic or botanical origin. I had a look at the IUPAC gold book which compiles chemical terminology and there is no entry for "mineral". Assume then the definition in the Wikipedia or a good dictionary.

Comment: In general please use standard chemical nomenclature. You can ask what is standard use of course. Your question is a bit diffuse because "stone" is a common usage term, not a technical term. It refers to rocks of a certain size, and rocks are pure minerals or solid mixtures of various minerals. A second point of confusion is whether you are interested in compounds with a single element or only those excluding oxygen in their composition.

Comment: It's always interesting how people downvote questions, yet the top users are all replying it. Hypocrites lol.

Comment: @Minsky this question was closed twice: closed, reopened, closed by mods.

Comment: Mods get fed up of their boring job, and become convinced that they have the authority to shame on others (even if they do not understand at all what the post is about), so most SE sites have a growing number of questions asked by non-verified accounts. This behaviour is then normalised and copied by new users. (In the beginning though, when these sites wanted users, it was quite friendly. Now business matters more.) The simplest solution is to just ask with random accounts, currently.

Answer (score 3):

Most stones are silicates and aluminosilicates (which can be vaguely described as combinations of oxides), and thus do indeed contain oxygen. Among the rest, many are just oxides. Your impression was correct. Oxygen is ubiquitous. One doesn't get called [the most abundant element in Earth's crust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_elements_in_Earth%27s_crust) for nothing.

As for the minerals containing no oxygen: why, there are some. Pyrite is the first that comes to mind. [image: Pyrite]([Source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrite))

Despite its majestic look and the fact that you don't find it often among roadside stones, it is nowhere as rare as diamond. In fact it is quite cheap, hence the name *"fool's gold"*.

So it goes.

Comment: I wonder if the OP meant elemental minerals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_element_mineral

Comment: I think not. After all, it would be hard to expect any of those to contain oxygen.

Comment: @Mithoron I think this will be closed soon "of natural causes".

Comment: @Mithoron I object. The question is not too broad: it does have a meaningful answer. Maybe it was asked by a person who would not pass your intelligence test. Maybe. Actually, I like the idea of giving such test to anyone whom I converse with during the day. It would make a lot of things easier. But before such practice is instituted, I'd rather stick to my usual routine.

Comment: Ivan, the thing is this could have a hundred answers, each one telling about a different mineral - that's what makes it too broad. It's a typical HNQ material. The answer is there's loads upon loads of such minerals, that's pretty much that, but we could easily have half of mineralogy put here. But, oh well, maybe I worry too much...

Comment: This thing on the photo does not look like a stone. Looks more like an alloy.

Comment: @Anixx Please address the questions you have been asked in order to reopen the post. Pyrite is a mineral, iron sulfide.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are plenty:
-Sulfide (e.g. [Pyrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrite))
-Silicide (e.g. [Suessite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suessite)). Here is a good link: https://encyclopedia.pub/entry/18800
-Nitride ([Siderazot ($\ce{Fe3N_{1.33}}$) is the only terrestrial nitride mineral](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-163X/11/3/290))
-[Carbide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Carbide_minerals)
-Phosphide (e.g. [Schreibersite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreibersite))
-[Selenide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenide_minerals)
-[Halide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halide_mineral) (There are some non-oxygen ones)

Comment: But are they stones rather than volatiles, alloy-likes, salts or organic compounds?

Comment: They are minerals.

Comment: Petroleum is also mineral but not stone.

Comment: @Anixx Define "stone" in your question. Accordingly, answer will be modified.